# Pinning a virtual machine to a particular physical core in Openstack

Tags: openstack, cpu, openstack-autopilot

I have an Openstack autopilot deployment on 3 physical machine and intend to evaluate interference between collocates vms on a single physical core. For this purpose I'm looking for a detailed & Ubuntu-specific instructions on how to ***pin a vm to a specific pCpu*** so I could have multiple vms on the same core & go on to my experiment. Any advice would make a big difference on how much time I'm gonna spent in this step. Thanks.

Comment: I don't think you can...  Pinning is simply setting dedicate vcpu, I don't believe it's allocated to a specific physical core.  You would be losing abstraction and the defeat the purpose of being able to move instances from host to host.  I might be off base, so +1 for a definitive answer.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to either create a new flavour, or edit one of the existing flavours (using the admin credentials available in the Autopilot dashboard) - and follow the "CPU pinning section" of the OpenStack admin docs here: http://docs.openstack.org/admin-guide/compute-flavors.html#cpu-pinning-policy

Comment: I really appreciate your response